# How Can I make my React Button Component updates CSS only on the specific page?

Tags: reactjs

So I created this button component using the following code

```
      const STYLES = ['btn--primary', 'btn--outline', 'btn--test'];

      const SIZES = ['btn--medium', 'btn--large'];

      const DISPLAY = ['btn--show', 'btn--hidden'];

      export const Button = ({
        children,
        type,
        onClick,
        buttonStyle,
        buttonSize,
        buttonDisplay
      }) => {
        const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle)
          ? buttonStyle
          : STYLES[0];

        const checkButtonSize = SIZES.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize : SIZES[0];

        const checkButtonDisplay = DISPLAY.includes(buttonDisplay)
          ? buttonDisplay
          : DISPLAY[0];

        return (
          <Link to='/sign-up'>
            <button
              className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize} ${checkButtonDisplay}`}
              onClick={onClick}
              type={type}
            >
              {children}
            </button>
          </Link>
        );
```

So I have this button component inside of my navbar component and I also have it inside of my home page section component.

My issue is that whenever I shrink the page to mobile, I want to make the button component in the navbar to display: none and then on the home section I want it to show

What ends up happening is that since it's a component, any CSS style I add to it will go on any other page that is using the component, so basically my button disappears on the home page section when I need it to display

I tried to add an Id to the button component, but that didn't work

```
  <Button id='nav-btn' buttonStyle='btn--outline'>
        SIGN UP
      </Button>
```

and I don't know how I'd add a custom class or id to the navbar button without it applying to all the other button components on my homepage

Answer (score 0):

Hide it with an expression, e.g., `{ showButton && <Button /> }.` If `showButton` is true, you'll see the button, if not, you won't.

If you want to do it via CSS, use a media-query to set `display: none` on whatever screen size it's supposed to disappear on.

### Edit in response to the comment

```
@media (max-height: 960px) {
    display: none;
}
```

That reads, "If the height is less than `960px`, set this property."

If you want a "special" button that hides on a screen size, create a higher-order component that wraps your button.

```
const NinjaButton => () => {
    // do stuff
    return <Button cssOverrideProp={cssWithMediaQueryThatHides} />
}
```

In `Button`, you can conditionally apply that css,

```
className=`{/* your other css */ ${cssOverrideProp || ''}}`
```

Then you can use that button anywhere it's supposed to hide.

Comment: so I wrote some code that allows me to add a specific class that shows or hides the button, but now my issue is making it only disappear at 960px. I'm not sure how to implement that code

Comment: Disappear _smaller_ than 960px?

Comment: yeah cause right now I have this code ` <Button buttonDisplay='btn--hidden' buttonStyle='btn--outline'>` and basically my logic is if button has a buttonDisplay value set it equal to btn--hidden, but it hides it on any screen size, so I only need it to hide on screen smaller than 960px

Comment: but how do I add a specific css media query to a button component that has default classes? because idk how to target only the navbar button component? When I did media query is hides all buttons on my site, not the one I want

Comment: check the code I added above. It shows my logic for my button component and right now I added a checkButtonDisplay property , but my issue is it hides the button on all screens and Idk how to write the code to only make it disappear on 960px

Comment: @Brian okay, I misunderstood the problem a little bit.

Comment: So if I add `<Button buttonDisplay='btn--hidden' buttonStyle='btn--outline'>` it hides the button because of my logic, but this hides it on all screen sizes, so I don't know how I would only hide the button at @media  < 960px.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219503/discussion-between-yatrix-and-brian).